# Array.find only works with a constant value in comparator - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, find

I'm trying to get an item from an array:

```
const device = this.selectedDevtype.devices.find(item =>
    console.log(this.deviceID);
    return item.device_id === this.deviceID;
});
console.log(device);
```

Console log writes "4" for `this.deviceID`, and it returns undefined for `device` value.

[Log fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex4dx.png)

But if I put a hard coded value, it works:

```
const device = this.selectedDevtype.devices.find(item =>
    console.log(this.deviceID);
    return item.device_id === 4;
});
console.log(device);
```

[Log OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBspp.png)

Why the first function does not work? What's the error? Thanks.

My typescript version is 2.6.2, I'm working on Angular 5.

---

Effectively, i'm comparing a string and a number. A regret that I declared the type in the component class:

```
deviceID: number;
```

the angular material radiogroup was changing the type of variable to string:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="deviceID" (change)="updateDevice()">
  <mat-radio-button fxFlex="50"
    *ngFor="let device of selectedDevtype.devices" value="{{ device.device_id }}">
    [{{ device.key }}]{{ device.name }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Maybe this can help someone.

Comment: The value of `this` in your first sample of code is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not comparing a string to an integer?

Try:

```
const device = this.selectedDevtype.devices.find(item => +item.device_id === +this.deviceID)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `item.device_id` is not equal to 4 in any of the occurrences.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.